How do I compute the intra-rater intraclass correlation for a study design with some repeated measures?
How do I compute the intra-rater intraclass correlation for a study design with some repeated measures?
The study had approximately 1000 subjects rated (continuously 0-100%) by 500 raters. Each rater evaluated on average 100 subjects (variable from 30 to 200 subjects, raters were free to choose how many). Subjects were randomly assigned to raters, and each subject received approximately 35 ratings on average. While the raters were making the assessments, approximately 5% of the subjects they received to be rated were actually a repeat of some subject they had already assessed (randomly selected and at maximum, a subject was assessed twice by a rater).
The analysis of interest at the moment is the intra-rater variability in those repeated subjects. I would like to compute an ICC, but I could not find a proper way to do it for this study design. I have read Koo & Li, 2016, and others, but their descriptions doesn't seem to fit this study design.
My data is currently like this:



Subject
Rater
Value
Repeat




1
1
35
No


45
1
75
No


890
1
10
No


45
1
80
Yes


1
2
50
No


700
2
90
No



Using R, I imagine the proper way to compute this ICC is to create some lmer model and apply some formula to its variances, but I am not sure how to properly describe the model (for example, do I nest repeats in raters?) and what would be the appropriate formula.
Thanks

ref for Koo & Li, 2016?

Koo TK, Li MY. A Guideline of Selecting and Reporting Intraclass Correlation Coefficients for Reliability Research. J Chiropr Med. 2016 Jun;15(2):155-63. doi: 10.1016/j.jcm.2016.02.012. Epub 2016 Mar 31. Erratum in: J Chiropr Med. 2017 Dec;16(4):346. doi: 10.1016/j.jcm.2017.10.001. PMID: 27330520; PMCID: PMC4913118.

I'm not the best with iccs, but since you have gotten no answer: I don't think there is an inter-rater ICC that corresponds to your situation.
If you had no replicates by the same raters, the correct one would be in my understanding ICC(2,k), i.e. two-way random effects, k raters and consistency or absolute agreement depending on which you need. This is not the icc you get from an lmer model with random intercept of participant using the typical formula of participant variance divided by total variance. This (lmer) icc is the (1,1) type (one-way random, single measurement, absolute agreement) and that is usually not used for inter-rater reliability.
For inter-rater reliability ICCs in R, you can use the ICC function from the psych package. That gives you all types of ICCs. But with the replicates, I don't know whether any of them works.
This post has been helpful to me (it opens as a pdf).
